# Port framework 4.6 to asp.net core 1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I can't build a few test proyect that we have migrated from fwk 4.6 to asp.net core 1.
Here are the output result of build:

```
15>------ Rebuild All started: Project: EbookingCoreTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
15>Build started 31/8/2016 7:42:47 p. m..
15> 1>
15>CoreCompile:
15> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "D:\eBookingV4\tst\EbookingCoreTest" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies --no-incremental
15> Project EbookingCoreTest (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
15> Compiling EbookingCoreTest for .NETStandard,Version=v1.6
15> 1>
15>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
15> 1>
15>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run dotnet restore
15> 1>
15>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : 2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
15> 1>
15>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : 3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use dotnet pack to distribute libraries.
15>
15>Build FAILED.
15>

dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003121)

Product Information:
Version: 1.0.0-preview2-003121
Commit SHA-1 hash: 1e9d529

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.10586
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win10-x64
```

Anybody know why is this error?

Comment: Have you run `dotnet restore` before build ?

Comment: Can you post your `project.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you probably have to include this in you project.json as exactly described in the error message

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
}
```

But that would have been better to include your full project.json with your question. We have too few information now.